# Добавление класса при скролле, javascript

Tags: javascript, события, прокрутка

Как передать this в addEventListener?? 
Может кто-то оценить код и сказать что не так.
При скролле страницы,если элемент с классом boxClass появляется в поле зрения, ему добавляется новый класс animateClass.

```
(function () {
    var bind=function(fn, me){ 
        return function(){ 
            return fn.apply(me,arguments); 
        }; 
    };
    function Scroller(boxClass,animateClass){
        this.boxClass=boxClass||"emergence";
        this.animateClass=animateClass||"animated";
        this.lastScroll=0;
        this.handler=bind(this.scrollHandler,this);
    };
    Scroller.prototype.start=function(){
        window.addEventListener('scroll',this.handler,false);
    };
    Scroller.prototype.stop=function(){
        window.removeEventListener('scroll',this.handler,false);
    };
    Scroller.prototype.scrollHandler=function(){
        var scrollTop=window.pageYOffset||document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        if (scrollTop<this.lastScroll) {
            return false;
        };
        var box=document.querySelectorAll("."+this.boxClass);
        for (var i=box.length-1;i>=0;i--){
            if (box[i].getBoundingClientRect().top<document.documentElement.clientHeight) {
                box[i].classList.add(this.animateClass);
            };
        };
        this.lastScroll=scrollTop;
    };
    this.Scroller=Scroller;
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По поводу вашего примера. У меня работает с небольшой правкой.

**Вначале ответ:** В общем я в конце написал...

```
var scroller = new Scroller();
scroller.start();
```

... и все заработало.

**Теперь дополнения по коду:**

В самом конце кода:

```
this.Scroller=Scroller;
```

Этот кусок не совсем хорош, либо это опечатка либо непонимание как работает this. Она конечно заработает в вашем случае так, что Scroller окажется в глобальном объекте, но добавив 'use strict' мы вызовем ошибку. Лучше так:

```
window.Scroller=Scroller;
```

---

По поводу того, как передавать this в колбеках. Тут есть несколько вариантов.

1) Скопировать this во временную переменную, например

```
var that = this; // или self
window.addEventListener('scroll',function() {
    // Тут можно использовать that
    that.handler();
} ,false);
```

2) Использовать метод bind

```
window.addEventListener('scroll',(function() {
    this.handler()
}).bind(this) ,false);
```

*У вас там используется свой способ, свой bind. И он работает вроде верно.*

Comment: Меня беспокоит этот момент:
` this.handler=bind(this.scrollHandler,this);`
Понимаю,что так делать нельзя.
Но как передать метод объекта таким образом, что бы потом можно было удалить обработчик??
И вообще, нормально что объект вешает обработчик?

Comment: Ну у вас написано нормально, я бы изменил следующее:

* bind - можно использовать и обычный метод bind(this)
* Метод scrollHandler - он у нас не публичный его можно сделать отдельной функцией и доступа к нему из вне не будет. Т.е.:

`this.handler = scrollHandler.bind(this)`

Comment: По поводу добавления обработчика в объекте - да так можно, но после удаления объекта может остаться в памяти ссылка на функцию в обработчике события onClick что вызовет утечку памяти. Против этого можно использовать делегирование событий. Это когда вешается один обработчик на одно событие, а потом оповещает все подписанные на него объекты. Если объекта нет - то не вызываем у него метод отвечающий за событие.

*Почитайте про утечки памяти и паттерн Observable*

Comment: Убрал реализацию своего bind и изменил объявление на 
'function scrollHandler(){
...
}'
и
'this._handler=scrollHandler.bind(this);'

А как бы Вы реализовали такую задачу, хотя бы примерно?

Comment: Ну смотрите, зависит от того что должен делать ваш объект.
Если нам нужно обрабатывать только один класс html элементов, то можно вообще не создавать класс, по сути у нас будет singleton, т.е. уже существующий объект, а не его класс. Он будет в одном экземпляре и одно событие будет висеть на onscroll.
Если же разных html элементов которые надо отследить будет много, то вместо того, чтобы создавать на каждый класс элементов новый 'Scroller', нам следует добавить методы добавляющие пару `className => newClass`, например `scroller.addEl('.emergence2', '.animated2')` один объект и один слушатель.

Comment: Спасибо, думаю все-таки реализовать Observable.

Comment: Маленькие комментарии)
Основная цель уменьшить количество создаваемых объектов и слушателей. 
НО, если же нужно создавать множество объектов и у каждого должен быть свой слушатель, то: создается класс делегирующий событие, т.е. он будет хранить массив всех объектов подписанных на событие и один обработчик события в котором он пробегается по всем объектам и вызывает у них метод.
**Будьте внимательны: событие onscroll вызывается достаточно часто, это может вызвать проблемы с производительностью в случае большого числа подписчиков** Как вариант может делать задержку обработки через setTimeout.